# Equation about polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, systems-of-equations

Is it possible to find real numbers $x_0, x_1, A_0$ and $A_1$ such equation :

$$
(25a+32b+45c+80d) = A_0(ax_0^3 + bx_0^2 + cx_0 + d) +  A_1(ax_1^3 + bx_1^2 + cx_1 + d)
$$

is true for every real $a,b,c,d$ ?

Answer (score 1):

So you want to solve
\begin{align}
80&=A_0+A_1\\
45&=A_0x_0+A_1x_1\\
32&=A_0x_0^2+A_1x_1^2\\
25&=A_0x_0^3+A_1x_1^3\\
\end{align}
This is the start of the general solution formula 
$$
u_k=A_0x_0^k+A_1x_1^k
$$
for an order 2 linear recursive sequence $u_0=80,u_1=45, u_2=32, u_3=25,…$. Solving for $p,q$ in the recursion formula
$$
u_{k+2}=pu_{k+1}+qu_k
$$
for the first two relations gives
$$
32=p·45+q·80\\
25=p·32+q·45\\
$$
Since that is solvable, you can find $p$ and $q$, from that $x_0,x_1$ as solutions of the quadratic equation
$$
x^2-px-q=0
$$
and from the firstmost two equations the constants $A_0,A_1$.